# Can't change the ionic default icon in status bar when receive a push notification

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, push-notification

I'm trying to change de blank square in ionic push notification. When I send the request changing the **icon**, it doesn't works.

```
...

"notification": {
    "title": "title",
    "message": "message",
    "android": {
        "icon": "icon"
    }
}

...
```

But, when I send the request with the SAME file 'icon' but to change de **image** it works

```
...

"notification": {
    "title": "title",
    "message": "message",
    "android": {
        "image": "icon"
    }
}

...
```

Anyone already faced that problem?
I'm using [phonegap-plugin-push](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push) and I've already seen the documentation, but without success.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't know where the plugin was searching for the icon file to insert in the push notification icon, so I've tried to search more in it documentation.

Searching in phonegap-plugin-push documentation, I've found a section that explains how [phonegap-build](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/PHONEGAP_BUILD.md) works and this section has a topic [adding-resources](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/PHONEGAP_BUILD.md#adding-resources), which is a beta feature to add resource files automatically in Android platform, but this doesn't work (at least not for me).

So I've tried to create the folder with the icon file manually (the same folder which is discribed in documentation) in the Android drawable folder and it works!!

**PLUS:** I've tested in Android 6.* and it just recognize solid, black and white and .png push notification icon file.

I hope this question can helps you!!